# Can I update Alamofire to version 4 and still support iOS 8 in my app?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I have a conclution and since I am a beginner, I just want to get it confirmed by someone else.

In my iOS app (Swift 2.2, Xcode 7) that must support iOS 8, I use Alamofire for server communication. Now my conclusion is that I will not be able to migrate the app to Xcode 8 and Swift 2.3 or 3.0, since I then have to use Alamofire version 4 and that version doesn´t suport iOS 8. So  my app has to keep Alamofire version 3 which means that it has to stay Swift 2.2 and Xcode 7. Did i understand this correctly?

Alamofire 4 requirements:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md

Alamofire 3 requirements:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%203.0%20Migration%20Guide.md

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you can't Alamofire 4.0 **requirements:**

- iOS and tvOS 9.0+, macOS 10.11.0+, watchOS 2.0+
- Xcode 8.0+
- Swift 3.0+

If you would like to use Alamofire on iOS 8 or macOS 10.9, use the latest tagged 3.x release which supports both Swift 2.2 and 2.3.

[Reference](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md)

Answer (score 3):

[Alamofire 4.0 Migration Guide](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Alamofire%204.0%20Migration%20Guide.md) said,

> If you would like to use Alamofire on iOS 8 or macOS 10.9, use the
>   latest tagged 3.x release which supports both Swift 2.2 and 2.3.

So, if you want to update to Xcode 8, you can convert your project to Swift 2.3 and use Alamofire [3.5.0](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/releases/tag/3.5.0). This release supports Swift 2.3 and iOS 8+.

Answer (score 0):

Try my fork, https://github.com/tonyli508/AlamofireDomain, I pull the latest changes and disabled stream request feature, which targeting IOS 8.